# Files copied from USB drive to any directory on OSX Lion disappear on complete

Tags: usb, usb-storage, file-transfer, osx-lion

So, using Finder, I can locate a backed up file on an external USB drive, copy it or drag and drop it to a folder such as Documents or Downloads on OSX Lion and the progress bar will tick along till completion.  The file will flicker in the directory file list for a moment and then disappear.

If I use Terminal and the cp command to do the same copy the files will stay.  What's going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try relaunching Finder before anything else.

Comment: Same can happen when copying files from SD or via SMB - a simple "Killall finder" solves the problem - very annoying though...

Comment: From the Apple discussions forum repairing disk permissions presumably also seems to do the trick: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3200189?start=30&tstart=0 - didn't test it though.